# How to run compression in gnu parallel?

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

Hi I am trying to compress a file with the `bgzip` command

```
bgzip -c 001DD.txt > 001DD.txt.gz
```

I want to run this command in parallel. I tried:

```
parallel ::: bgzip -c 001DD.txt > 001DD.txt.gz
```

but it gives me this error:

```
parallel: Error: Cannot open input file 'bgzip': No such file or directory
```

Comment: `ls -1 *.tar.* | parallel tar xvf` folder containing tar files

Comment: `parallel -j10 "gzip {}" ::: *.txt` You can try

Comment: You want to run `bgzip` in parallel with which other command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to chop the big file into smaller chunks and compress these. It can be done this way:

```
parallel --pipepart -a 001DD.txt --block -1 -k bgzip > 001DD.txt.gz
```